# jQuery tutorial - code not working?

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery, and I am going through a set of video tutorials. Today was the first one, and I did all that I was told in the video, but it doesn't work. The first tutorial was about to fadeout a simple  tag. I wrote the following code with CSS and scripting tags.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hi</title>
    <script src = "http://www.myvirtualhost.lcl:8080/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type= "text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<style type = "text/css">
    #box
    {
    background: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    }
</style> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        alert("hi");
        $('#box').fadeOut();
        )};
    });
</script>
<body>
    <div id="box"></div>
    <a href="#">Click Me !</a>
</body>
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, and why it is not working?

Comment: explain what "it is not working" means....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`)};` should be `});` since you need to close the anonymous function block first before closing the `click(` argument list.

By the way, you should properly indent your code:

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        alert("hi");
        $('#box').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Additionally, having the firebug debugger/console open is a good idea - then you quickly see any errors such as the parse error in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert("hi");
    $('#box').fadeOut();
    )};
```

Should be:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert("hi");
    $('#box').fadeOut();
    });
```

If you are using Firefox, I would recommend that you install FireBug, which is a developers' tool that allows you to debug your javascript/css/html.

Answer (score 2):

There is a **syntax error** in your JavaScript code:

```
    $('#box').fadeOut();
    )};
```

*Should be:*

```
    $('#box').fadeOut();
    });
```

Working end result here: http://jsfiddle.net/GTCfR/

*(You will most likely appreciate [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net), by the way, as it is ideal for doing simple tests like this and learning the basics.)*

Comment: You should also learn to use the console, whether the webkit one or firebug's. Surely this syntax mistake would raise an error and be shown there.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<style>` and `<script>` tags need to be placed within the head or body of the document. Nothing can exist in the nether region between the two.

As noted by others, there is also a syntax error here:

```
)};
```

It should be

```
});
```

You may wish to consider installing Firebug for Firefox or use the Chrome developer tools. They each include a Javascript console that will reveal Javascript errors.

Comment: While true it is not the reason for his problem.

Answer (score 1):

You hav a syntax error in line

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        alert("hi");
        $('#box').fadeOut();
        )}; <------------ Error here. It must be });
    });
```

Then it will work !

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6WqvN/)

Answer (score 0):

Almost perfect! However, in the following code, you've got the )}; mixed up. Look right after the `.fadeOut();` part of the code.

```
 $(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
    alert("hi");
    $('#box').fadeOut();
    )}; <!-- This needs swapped, to look like });-->
}); <!-- this one -->
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert("hi");
    $('#box').fadeOut();
    return false;///add this line
    }); // and change this line
```

Maybe you can add this to your click action